# How to properly include Spring into an OSGified bundle

Tags: spring, maven, osgi

I have a very simple OSGI app that just listens on register/unregister and sends some message to stdout.

What I have in my app is a simple Spring initialized bean. I use the maven bundle plugin to bundle the jar and put it into felix. This is an exceprt of the pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>org.spring.*</Export-Package>
                    <Bundle-Activator>foo.bar.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The project compiles just fine and can be deployed into Felix just fine, however, when the activator is called, it complains about missing dependency like that:

> Unresolved constraint in bundle foo.bar.project [56]: Unable to
>   resolve 56.0: missing requirement [56.0] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.context)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))

I tried changing this line:

org.spring.*

To this:

*

In which felix complains that android-dalvik is not present, so I am completely clueless.

Any idea how to include Spring in an OSGI project without using Spring DM?

EDIT: Here is what the generated manifest complains about (from web console)

> Exported Packages
>
> foo.bar.osgi foo.bar.service foobar.tracker
>
> Imported Packages  org.osgi.framework,version=[1.6,2) from
>   org.apache.felix.framework (0) org.osgi.util.tracker,version=[1.5,2)
>   from org.apache.felix.framework (0) ERROR:
>   org.springframework.context,version=[3.1,4) -- Cannot be resolved
>   ERROR: org.springframework.context.support,version=[3.1,4) -- Cannot
>   be resolved
>
> Manifest Headers  Bnd-LastModified: 1339014840268
>
> Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_32
>
> Built-By: fooBar
>
> Bundle-Activator: foo.bar.osgi.Activator
>
> Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
>
> Bundle-Name: fooBar
>
> Bundle-SymbolicName: foo.bar.OSGIProject
>
> Bundle-Version: 0.20.0.SNAPSHOT
>
> Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
>
> Export-Package:  foo.bar.osgi.tracker; uses:="foo.bar.osgi.service,
>   org.osgi.util.tracker, org.osgi.framework",
>
> foo.bar.osgi; uses:="org.springframework.context.support,
>   org.springframework.context, org.osgi.framework", foo.bar.osgi.service
>
> Import-Package:
>
> org.osgi.framework; version="[1.6, 2)", org.osgi.util.tracker;
>   version="[1.5, 2)", org.springframework.context; version="[3.1, 4)",
>   org.springframework.context.support; version="[3.1, 4)"
>   Manifest-Version: 1.0 Tool: Bnd-1.15.0

This is when I changed in pom

```
<configuration>
    <instructions>
        <Include-Resource>src/main/resources/spring-beans.xml</Include-Resource>
        <Bundle-Activator>nl.synovite.scheduled.osgi.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>></instructions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated MANIFEST.MF? And why are you exporting "org.spring"? Is that the package name of your code base?

Comment: I think org.spring.* is being exported as a way of re-packaging every spring dependency into the built bundle. If you must repackage spring in your bundle (which isn't really in the modularity spirit of OSGi, imo), <Private-Package> might be better than <Export-Package>. This at least avoids exposing all the spring internals.

Comment: Private package is indeed a better choice in this case (actually as far as I know, privatePackage is discarded in manifest by most OSGI providers). However, private or no, spring is not packaged at all into the jar. So I went ahead and added all spring dependencies in felix as osgified artifacts.

Comment: Private-package is, as you say, a build instruction rather than a runtime one. This avoids mixing build concerns with runtime behaviour. (See my answer below for why neither instruction packages spring.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think your bundle is basically fine, but Felix seems unable to resolve the org.springframework packages, so you need to add some bundle that exports the org.springframework packages. I don't know spring well, but I guess you can download those bundles from springsource.

Maven must have found one too as it seemed to be able to compile it.

Comment: The problem is it does compile the artifact but doesn't include the spring libs in the generated bundle. If I add the libraries as bundles from springsource, it seems to find them. Weird, imo.

Comment: It can be confusing, but the thing to remember is that Maven manages build-time dependencies, and OSGi runtime dependencies. Maven has no idea how or when you want to add runtime dependencies, it just creates a bundle that will work if its dependencies are also present at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

```
<Export-Package>org.spring.*</Export-Package>
```

but the package of interest is `org.springframework.context`. The export syntax is a pattern, not a full regex, so the dot in your export really means dot (i.e. a package delimiter), and not an arbitrary character.

```
<Export-Package>org.spring*</Export-Package>
```

should do what you want.

Comment: I also tried this, but then it complained about unresolved dependencies. If I included them, it complained for more unresolved dependencies. I tried also to include *, but, of course, more unresolved deps. So I guess I was better off adding the osgified spring deps in felix.

Comment: I agree that using a pre-existing osgified bundle is better than trying to create your own. When you export *, have a look in your bundle. You may be surprised how much has been dragged in. Putting the entire class path in one bundle is definitely not in the spirit of OSGi!